# wp_enqueue_scrpts seems not to get called

Tags: plugins, javascript

I know this is very unlikely that it is not really called, so most likely I entered the function on some wrong place.

What is the situation. I have a plugin running which interfaces with another plugin AND woocommerce. Because of the update by WooCommerce 3.0 the select2 script isn't working anymore as it should and it creates kinda mess in the user interface at the dashboard.

So I thought a nice solution would be to -if a variable 'non_conflict_mode' would be set, the old select2 script would be dequeued. In theory a great solution.

So I entered in my plugin completely at the beginning this code :

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wxp_patch',99);
function wxp_patch() {
   wp_dequeue_script('scripthandle');  
}
```

Since nothing happened, I thought to put something else in the patch function like

```
function wxp_patch() {
    die('Died trying');
}
```

Also didn't work. Nobody died, the expected form showed up. Only still using the 'faulty' script.

I used this method a million time (well, almost) in function.php's... It should work in a plugin too, doesn't it? If it should, any idea what I have been doing wrong?

Btw, the file is normally called, because all the code in the file is normally executed.

Comment: you can try Hook priority set 100. Just try it . i hope it's work. i am not sure about this.

Comment: Well I even tried at 999 and it didn't work. With the 'die' it also should not matter. As soon as the function with 'die' is called, the script should end, disregarding the priority it is called with.

Comment: Have you [enabled error logging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and checked these logs?

Comment: Yes. It is a development environment and I always have full error display to screen, from notices to fatal.

Comment: your code is working for me perfectly.`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wxp_patch',99);
function wxp_patch() {
   wp_dequeue_script('jpushmenu');
}`

Comment: And you run it from a plugin ?
I tried in a function.php and it runs ok too... only it somehow doesn't from the plugin...